# Is it possible to easily make an indexed array associative in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a multidimentional array already made, brought in from a CSV file via csvlib

I also have the headers in an array and I would like a way to assign this array as the keys for the arrays.

here's a simplification

have a data array like so

data[0] -> [0] blue, [1] 1984, [2] wednesday
[1] -> [0] green, [1] 1926, [2] friday

and a simple array of keys/properties (header array) like so:

[0] colour, [1] year, [2] weekday

I'd like to insert the keys to make
data[0] -> [colour] blue, [year] 1984, [weekday] wednesday
[1] -> [colour] green, [year] 1926, [weekday] friday

i've read up into associative arrays a bit and am not getting how to do this. (there's 38 properties so remember which is which in a straight indexed array is going to be quite inconvenient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just want your second-level array to be a simple object instead. Let me show you some code:

```
var data:Array = [];

var record1:Object = {"colour": "blue", "year": "1984", "weekday": "wednesday"};
var record2:Object = {"colour": "green", "year": "1926", "weekday": "friday"};

data.push(record1);
data.push(record2);

trace("record 1:", data[0]["colour"], data[0]["year"], data[0]["weekday"]);
trace("record 2:", data[1]["colour"], data[1]["year"], data[1]["weekday"]);
```

Output:

```
record 1: blue 1984 wednesday
record 2: green 1926 friday
```

So I would convert the data array into the structure you want, something like this:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var record:Array = data[i];
  var newRecord:Object = {};

  for (var index:int in record)
    newRecord[headers[index]] = record[index];  

  data[i] = newRecord;
}
```

Now your data array is an array of associative arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your CSV uses `;` as field separator, you read the CSV using URLLoader, and loading completes successfully.

In your completeHandler, you will now call `csvToArray(loader.data as String);`.

```
private function csvToArray ( data : String ) : Array
{
    var lines : Array = data.split ( /\R/ );
    var keyArray : Array = lines.splice ( 0, 1 )[0].split ( ";" );
    var assocArray : Array = [];
    for each (var line:String in lines)
    {
        var valArray : Array = line.split ( ";" );
        var assoc : Object = {};
        for (var i : int = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++)
        {
            var key : String = keyArray[i];
            if (key != null && key != "") assoc[key] = valArray[i];
        }
        assocArray.push ( assoc );
    }
    return assocArray;
}
```

Here's what happens:

1. Read CSV's first line into `keyArray`
2. Read each remaining line into `valArray`
3. Use both to populate `assocArray`